# How to use 2 arrays in a foreach loop PHP for choosing random element

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

I have two arrays:

```
$array1 = array("red", "blue", "green", "yellow");
$array2 = array("one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten");
```

I want to randomly echo 10 times a color.

I tried to do it using `foreach` loop and `shuffle`, but when I try this I am getting the error:

> Array to string conversion.....

This is my code:

```
shuffle($array1);
foreach($array2 as $array2) {
    echo $array1;
}
```

Please can someone help me solving this problem?

Comment: check your idea in correct syntax : https://eval.in/1111066

Comment: cbk38  did length of `$array2` can increase or decrease? or it will be always 10?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You messing between array variable and their element.

First, you cannot do `echo $array1;` as the variable is array and echo is for string. Second, `foreach($array2 as $array2)` is reassign `$array2` as both element so the original array is mess-up.

Better way to do that will be with [array_rand](https://php.net/array_rand):

```
foreach(range(1,10) as $v) {
    echo $array1[array_rand($array1)] . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`while`-variation of another answer:

```
$i = 0;
while ($i++ < 10) {
    echo $array1[array_rand($array1)];
}
```